# How do you plot pairwise comparisons with the letters for an interaction of GLMM

Tags: plot, glm, tukey

This is my model:

```
mod6<-glmer(NS.test~0+Beach*method+(1|year)+ (1|Beach/Zone_1/index),data=y2,weights=(y2$FC+y2$Nest),family=binomial)
```

I did multiple comparisons:

```
    wht <- glht(mod6, linfct = mcp(Beach = "Tukey", method = "Tukey"))
```

summary(wht, test = adjusted("Westfall"))

results:

```
> wht <- glht(mod6, linfct = mcp(Beach = "Tukey", method = "Tukey"))
Warning messages:
1: In mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) :
  covariate interactions found -- default contrast might be inappropriate
2: In mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) :
  covariate interactions found -- default contrast might be inappropriate
    > summary(wht, test = adjusted("Westfall"))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glmer(formula = NS.test ~ 0 + Beach * method + (1 | year) + (1 | 
Beach/Zone_1/index), data = y2, family = binomial, weights = (y2$FC + 
y2$Nest))

Linear Hypotheses:
                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Beach: HO/HA - Hillsboro == 0       0.28208    0.13787   2.046   0.0408 *  
Beach: P/FTL - Hillsboro == 0       0.45910    0.11874   3.866   <0.001 ***
Beach: P/FTL - HO/HA == 0           0.17703    0.06999   2.529   0.0196 *  
method: HTL only - HTL and SB == 0  0.64003    0.13472   4.751   <0.001 ***
method: no clean - HTL and SB == 0  0.36418    0.08201   4.441   <0.001 ***
method: no clean - HTL only == 0   -0.27585    0.10690  -2.581   0.0196 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- Westfall method)
```

This was the only way I found the multiple comparisons to work. As you can see I have an error.
Any idea what it means?

How do I plot the results with the letters above them?

Is there a different way to do the multiple comparisons with an interaction another way?

Comment: 1 - You have 'warnings' not 'errors' (errors would have prevented execution of the function), the warnings are indicating that you have interaction terms so any interpretation of main effects should take that into account (as per standard statistics guidance).  2 - You should make the question about plotting a separate post AFTER reading the many existing posts at stackoverflow and elsewhere on that topic.  3 - I'm not sure but you might find this helpful: http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2011/06/glmm-with-custom-multiple-comparisons.html